# Google Sheet Script to remove "Make a Copy" or "Download" from editors permissions?

Tags: user-interface, google-apps-script, google-sheets, editor

I am looking to use a sheet I've created to sell it to others. I want to be able to give them access to edit/print the sheets, but not to be able to download or make a copy.

I understand that you can limit those options by making the users "viewers" or "collaborators", but as far as I know, it's not possible to limit those options if the other user is an "editor", which is what I need.

That said, is there some sort of script / protection code I can write to remove these options from the editors UI?

I've looked everywhere.

Comment: No, there's no way to do that. Maybe deploying it as a web app could be a good workaround for your situation? Could you give more details on this?